# HttpAsyncClient isn't making request if setConnectionManagerShared is set to true

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient, asynchttpclient, apache-httpasyncclient

For some reason `HttpAsyncClient` isn't making request if `setConnectionManagerShared` is set to `true`. I found this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPASYNC-83) but couldn't figure out what I'm missing.

Here is how I create new client

```
def apply(proxy: Option[HttpHost], cookieStore: Option[CookieStore]) = {

val builder = HttpAsyncClients.custom.
  setConnectionManager(connManager).
  setConnectionManagerShared(true).
  setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).
  setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).
  setSSLStrategy(sslStrategy)

proxy.map(builder.setProxy)
builder.setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore.getOrElse(new BasicCookieStore)) // Use custom cookie store if necessary.

// Create an HttpClient with the given custom dependencies and configuration.
val client: HttpAsyncClient = new HttpAsyncClient(builder.build)
client
}
```

Full class is located is [here](https://gist.github.com/cppexpert/e0a7fcabaa5d3abe8f05).

What should I change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DefaultConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor();
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor);

CloseableHttpAsyncClient client1 = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client2 = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
        .build();

client1.start();
client2.start();

final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
FutureCallback callback = new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(HttpResponse result) {
        latch.countDown();
        System.out.println(result.getStatusLine());
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Exception ex) {
        latch.countDown();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {
        latch.countDown();
    }
};

client1.execute(new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get"), callback);
client2.execute(new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get"), callback);
latch.await();

// I am aware this is sloppy
client1.close();
client2.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that it's not working because I call `setConnectionManagerShared` for every created client ? And if yes does it mean I need to "owning" client non-closed?

Comment: There should be a service responsible for starting up and shutting down the underlying the I/O reactor. It is easier to accomplish by one client 'owning' the connection manager, but also can be done completely independently.

Comment: Got it. I'll keep one dummy client in my singleton then. It seems bit hackish to me though.

Comment: As I said you do not need to do so. You can also maintain an instance of IOReactor and control its life cycle in your singleton.

Comment: You will effectively have to duplicate most of this code http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/httpasyncclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/nio/client/CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.html#40

Comment: What should I use as `IOEventDispatch` ? `InternalIODispatch` is package only class.

Comment: You can use DefaultHttpClientIODispatch or extend AbstractIODispatch